# How can I stop getting the error message self is not defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

class numbers:
    
    def numGen(self):
        self.num1 = random.randint(100,9999)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1,9)
    
    def question(self):
        self.questions = str(self.num1) + " X " + str(self.num2)
        print(self.question)
    
    numGen(self)
    question(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers()
```

Whenever I try and run my code I get the error message "undefined variable self".
I'm not sure on how to fix this. Any help will the apricated thanks.

Comment: idk much abt classes but is it not compulsory to `def __init__(self):`?

Comment: in `numGen(self)` and `question(self)` you are out of an operation where *self* is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare an *instance* of the `numbers` class and then call those methods on the instance, instead of directly in the class.

```
import random

class numbers:
    
    def numGen(self):
        self.num1 = random.randint(100,9999)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1,9)
    
    def question(self):
        self.questions = str(self.num1) + " X " + str(self.num2)
        print(self.questions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myNumbers = numbers()
    myNumbers.numGen()
    myNumbers.question()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much apricated

Answer (score 1):

Self is used to refer to a variable field within the class also it is used to represent the instance of the class (the case where self is as a keyword inside a function).

```
import random


class numbers:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.numGen()
        self.question()

    def numGen(self):
        self.num1 = random.randint(100, 9999)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1, 9)

    def question(self):
        self.questions = str(self.num1) + " X " + str(self.num2)
        print(self.questions) # You had a typo here


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers()
```

Comment: self isn't a keyword

Comment: This is almost a code-only answer. Please explain what you've changed, and why, to make this a much better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much apricated

Comment: also speak about to replace `print(self.question)` by `print(self.questions)` because this is probably what the OP wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by bruno and the answer by John Gordon your calls to `numGen(self)` and `question(self)` are at the class level not inside an method of the class where `self` would be defined. That means they are executed when the class is created not when an instance of the class is created and self is not defined there. You need to move them out to somewhere else.  I am not going to talk about that since it is already dealt with.

However you have an additional problem. Your `numGen()` method is what declares and assigns values to `self.num1` and `self.num2`. Those values are used but not assigned in the method `question()`. You do not have an `__init__()` that defines them and so until `numGen()` is called they do not exist.

That means that if you ever call `numGen()` before `numGen()` your code will throw an exception and fail. To prevent that you need to capture that exception and handle it, which does not really seem to make sense, or you need to ensure they are defined when an instance is instantiated, which means doing it in an `__init__()` which you do not currently have.

Looking at the code, it does not seem to make sense that the operations done in `numGen()` are not in the init when the instance is created. SO you might want to change it to something like this:

```py
import random
    
class numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numGen()
        
    def numGen(self):
        self.num1 = random.randint(100,9999)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1,9)
        
    def question(self):
        self.questions = str(self.num1) + " X " + str(self.num2)
        print(self.questions)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myNumbers = numbers()
    myNumbers.question()

    myNumbers.numGen()
    myNumbers.question()
```

The above is similar to the answer from John Gordon, but does not initially call `numGen()` since they are already generated. I left `numGen()` and called it from the init instead of replacing it so that you could call it repeatedly as shown. If you do not need that then you would just move the contents of `numGen()` directly into the `__init__()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

`self` is used as a placeholder for the object. Use it as a method, like this:

```
self.method()
```

The `self` parameter is automatically filled in.

Comment: and "undefined variable self" will be still true, you do not solve the error just replacing `numGen(self)`by `self.numGen()` and same for *question*  in the OP code

Answer (score -1):

For calling class method in class need to use `[object].method()` syntax. as per @Stick-Figure answer.

```
import random


class numbers:
    def __init__(self):
        self.numGen()
        self.question()

    def numGen(self):
        self.num1 = random.randint(100, 9999)
        self.num2 = random.randint(1, 9)

    def question(self):
        self.questions = str(self.num1) + " X " + str(self.num2)
        print(self.questions)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers()
```

Comment: This won't work.  `self.numGen()` is at the outermost class level, where `self` does not exist.

Comment: @PrashantGodhani yes this is that, so I removed my DV. There are lot of answers saying the same thing now ... :)